# OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI" for linked server "MY_DB" returned message "Communication link failure"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I have linked MS SQL 2008 to MS SQL 2005 when try to execute the query, i have the following error:

```
OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI" for linked server "MY_DB"  returned message "Communication link failure".
Msg 64, Level 16, State 1, Line 0
TCP Provider: The specified network name is no longer available.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: AFAIK, you can't use link server for SQL 2008 from SQL 2005

Comment: Well few other points: 1> can you ping that DB server where the link is trying to connect? 2> Have you checked SQL server setting to see whether `Remote Connection` is set to `True`; default will be `False`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you using for the IP configuration?
Are you using the IP or the computer Name for the configuration?

This problem can occur if you are using a static IP in your configuration and your server has a dynamic IP, but this is assuming you have this configuration on the client and the server. It is better if you give the configuration that you used.